# How to write a PyArrow isin expression on tuples

Tags: pyarrow

I have a (large) pyarrow dataset whose columns contains, among others, `first_name` and `last_name`. I'd like to filter the dataset to only get rows where the pair `first_name, last_name` is in a given list of pairs.

I know how to write a pyarrow dataset `isin` expression on one field (e.g. `pc.field("last_name").isin(my_last_names)`), but I'm lost on how to write the same expression on *tuples* of fields.

Answer (score 1):

`isin` isn't (yet / asof pyarrow==13.0.0) supported on list/struct data type.

You can use a join instead:

```py
left = pa.table(
    {
        "first_name": ["John", "George", "David"],
        "last_name": ["Smith", "Smith", "Johnson"]
    }
)
right = pa.table(
    {
        "first_name": ["John", "George"],
        "last_name": ["Smith", "Jonhson"]
    }
)


left.join(right, keys=['first_name', 'last_name'], join_type='left semi')
```

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| John | Smith |

Using `pa.struct` doesn't work:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

pa.table(
    {
        "name": [
            {"first": "John", "last": "Smith"},
            {"first": "George", "last": "Smith"},
            {"first": "David", "last": "Johnson"},
        ]
    }
).filter(
    pc.field("name").isin(
        pa.array(
            [
                {"first": "John", "last": "Smith"},
                {"first": "George", "last": "Johnson"},
            ]
        )
    )
)
```

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Function 'is_in' has no kernel matching input types (struct<first: string, last: string>)

Neither does using `pa.list_`:

```py
pa.table(
    {
        "name": [
            ["John", "Smith"],
            ["George", "Smith"],
            ["David", "Johnson"],
        ]
    }
).filter(
    pc.field("name").isin(
        pa.array(
            [
                ["John", "Smith"],
                ["George", "Johnson"],
            ]
        )
    )
)
```

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Function 'is_in' has no kernel matching input types (list<item: string>)